# Dimen attributes not working in deutsch language android

Tags: android

I am using checkbox and add padding with dimen value

```
<dimen name="padding_checkbox">25dp</dimen>
```

I have created a v-17 folder for large device too and set

```
<dimen name="padding_checkbox">5dp</dimen>
```

Now I'm testing my app on nexus in English, it's returning the expected result, but when I change the language of the device and set it to Deutsch(german), my checkbox padding gets too big, I tried checking the padding value with

```
int px = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_checkbox);
```

and  get 7 in English and 33 in Deutsch(german), I cannot understand why this is happening.

Comment: first of all v-14 folder is for android api version 14.not a large devices.

Comment: Please format your question better next time. It was barely understandable before I edited it.

Comment: @Imtiyaz ahhh, it was an mistake, Please check updated question

Answer (score 1):

I think you have mentioned this

```
<dimen name="padding_checkbox">25dp</dimen>
```

in values-de ,thats why this is happening(may be).
Try to remove it, if exists.